# Parse filterResults findObjects vs findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, search, parse-platform

I am filling a tableview in my app with Parse data and then allowing my users to sift through that data with a search field. Long story short it works fine except I am receiving a `A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread` error. I know it is on this line `NSArray *results = [query findObjects];` so I figured I would run a `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` to try to fix that. Well it did but now the tableview always comes up empty. Should I not worry about the warning? If I should be, what is wrong with the code? Thanks!

Search Works But Gets Warning:

```
-(void)filterResults:(NSString *)searchTerm {

    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"NHLVideos"];
    [query whereKey:@"User" containsString:searchTerm];
    NSArray *results = [query findObjects];
    [self.searchResults addObjectsFromArray:results];
}
```

No Warning But No Search Results :

```
-(void)filterResults:(NSString *)searchTerm {

    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"NHLVideos"];
    [query whereKey:@"User" containsString:searchTerm];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error){
            //No Error
            [self.searchResults addObjectsFromArray:objects];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
        }
    }];
}
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, the query runs on the main thread, so the program waits until the query returns before continuing.  This is less than ideal, since your app could halt for an indeterminate amount of time until the query returns - hence the warning message.

The second case is preferred, because the query runs in background on another thread.  Regarding your missing results, perhaps the query is returning the results, but you are checking on the main thread before the query has finished running.  Again, you can never be sure how long the query will take to run.  The table needs to be reloaded inside the block after you add `objects` to `self.searchResults`.  In other words, at some point in the future, the query will finish and then run the block.  You add the results to the `self.searchResults` but the tableView will not get reloaded right away, and you will not show up although they were retrieved by the query.

On a side note, in a block, you should not be referencing self.  The object has a strong reference to the block, and now the block has a strong reference to the object - i.e. a retain cycle / memory leak.  To correct this add:

`__weak MyObject *weakSelf = self;`

before the block and use `weakSelf` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Very detailed and helpful though when I run the block but add the `[self.tableView reloadData];` after the `searchResults` received the objects, my tableview still does not display any objects.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Josh Gafni. This works perfectly!

```
 -(void)filterResults:(NSString *)searchTerm {

        [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"NHLVideos"];
        [query whereKey:@"User" containsString:searchTerm];
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error){
                //No Error
                [self.searchResults addObjectsFromArray:objects];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
        });
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
            }
        }];
    }
```